# Speed parameter has no effect when cursor is moved with pyclick's HumanCurve

Tags: python

Trying to use the HumanCurve function from [pyclick](https://github.com/patrikoss/pyclick).
However, I find that the cursor moves for the same duration between two points regardless of distance.
The Github states that the duration can be changed within the function as such:

```
# move the mouse to position (100,100) on the screen in approximately 2 seconds
hc.move((100,100),2)
```

I am currently using the following in my code:

```
hc.move((random.randint(432, 460), random.randint(330, 353)), random.uniform(0.1,0.6))
```

But this seems to have no effect on the duration of the movement. Decreasing the duration in the function does not actually reduce the time taken to move between points, and neither does increasing it, it seems.

How can I decrease the duration of movement?